# list view doesn't respond to clicks /condition issue

Tags: java, android, list, listview, listener

I wrote an item click listener for my list view and it's working for me but the problem is the only item that responds to clicks is the first one , the others do not. When I move the cursor on position==1 it shows me this message. I don't know that to do.

[image]

Here is the method I'm using:

```java
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         if (position == 0) {
             Intent items = new Intent(MainActivity.this, items.class);
             startActivity(items);
             if (position == 1) {
                 Intent Category = new Intent(MainActivity.this, category.class);
                 startActivity(Category);
                 if (position == 2) {
                     Intent discounts = new Intent(MainActivity.this, discounts.class);
                     startActivity(discounts);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you are putting last two conditions  inside position  0 condition in simple words its issue  with you Curley  brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You have nested the `if condition`

**Corrct solution:**

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
             if (position == 0) {
                 Intent items = new Intent(MainActivity.this, items.class);
                 startActivity(items);
             }
                 if (position == 1) {
                     Intent Category = new Intent(MainActivity.this, category.class);
                     startActivity(Category);
             }
                     if (position == 2) {
                         Intent discounts = new Intent(MainActivity.this, discounts.class);
                         startActivity(discounts);
                     }

...
```